# HTTP response to invalid proxy authentication?

Tags: http, authentication, https, proxy

If a proxy server requires authorization it returns an HTTP 407 ("Proxy Authentication Required") status code.

However, ***what happens if a proxy server is provided authorization which is invalid***? Does it return another HTTP 407 or an HTTP 401 ("Unauthorized") or ...? (A use-case might be where `System.Net.WebClient` from .NET uses the "default proxy credentials" which happen to be invalid.)

I wouldn't mind some "steps to try it out myself", but my HTTP-foo is weak and I have no such proxy server myself (so it's more of a hypothetical question for me at this point). I have skimmed through [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) (including "14.34 Proxy-Authorization") but I was not able to glean anything -- very possibly an oversight on my part -- and references to the applicable sections describing the behavior are also very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt):

> If a proxy does not accept the
>   credentials sent with a    request, it
>   SHOULD return a 407 (Proxy
>   Authentication Required).

Comment: Awesome. +1 and a pink pony for you!